# How to generate __init__.py in all subdirectories of current directory in cmake?

Tags: python, cmake, protocol-buffers

I use an out-of-tree builds with CMake.
I have a CMake custom command that generates *_pb2.py files from proto-files.
Since proto-files may reside in an unknown number of subdirectories (package namespace), like `$SRC/package1/package2/file.proto`, then the build directory will contain something like `$BLD/package1/package2/file_pb2.py`.

I want to implicitly make packages from auto-generated *_pb2.py files and, thus, I want to automagically generate __init__.py files in all subfolders (`$BLD/package1`, `$BLD/package1/package2`, etc.) and then install them.

How can I do that?

*P.S.* I've tried macro from [CMake : How to get the name of all subdirectories of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787823/cmake-how-to-get-the-name-of-all-subdirectories-of-a-directory) (changed **GLOB** to **GLOB_RECURSE**) but it returns only subdirs that contain files. I can't get `package1` subdir from example above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should give you a list of directories as required in the variable `AllPaths`:

```
# Get paths to all .py files (relative to build dir)
file(GLOB_RECURSE SubDirs RELATIVE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/*.py")
# Clear the variable AllPaths ready to take the list of results
set(AllPaths)
foreach(SubDir ${SubDirs})
  # Strip the filename from the path
  get_filename_component(SubDir ${SubDir} PATH)
  # Change the path to a semi-colon separated list
  string(REPLACE "/" ";" PathParts ${SubDir})
  # Incrementally rebuild path, appending each partial path to list of results
  set(RebuiltPath ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
  foreach(PathPart ${PathParts})
    set(RebuiltPath "${RebuiltPath}/${PathPart}")
    set(AllPaths ${AllPaths} ${RebuiltPath})
  endforeach()
endforeach()
# Remove duplicates
list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES AllPaths)
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are working under a *NIX os (including mac) you could use the shell find command like:

```
ROOT="./"
for DIR in $(find $ROOT -type d); do
    touch $DIR/__init__.py
done
```

or with a python script:

```
from os.path import isdir, walk, join

root = "/path/to/project"
finit = '__init__.py'
def visitor(arg, dirname, fnames):
    fnames = [fname for fname in fnames if isdir(fname)]
    # here you could do some additional checks ...
    print "adding %s to : %s" %(finit, dirname)
    with open(join(dirname, finit), 'w') as file_: file_.write('')

walk(root, visitor, None)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one-line version of the other answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/11449316/827437:

`find $DIR -type d -exec touch {}/__init__.py \;`

This creates an `__init__.py` file within every directory in $DIR, by executing the `touch` command. Run `find $DIR -type d` to see the directories that will include the file.

Comment: @Leonard sure, clarified.

Comment: Thank you. I deleted my comment and upvoted your answer.