# Adding header and .cpp files in a project built with cmake

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, header, cmake, project

I have built a project using cmake and some libraries.I want however to add some header and .cpp files in the project which I am going to code.What is the easiest way to do it?Can I just create a .cpp and header files and then build again project in Visual Studio? Or due to the fact that project was built using cmake I can't?

Comment: Have you tried it? I think that you can check if you can't yourself.

Comment: Tell us what you have tried. CMake comes with a Visual Studio project generator: if you use that, and then load the project in Visual Studio, Visual Studio should be able to call cmake automatically every time you modify your cmake files, for example to add a new source file. Note: you usually don't need to do anything in particular if you add a new header, only if you add a new source file.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can put all header/source files in the same folder and use something like

```
file(GLOB SOURCES
    header-folder/*.h
    source-folder/*.cpp
)

add_executable(yourProj ${SOURCES})
```

In this way, you can do either of the following two methods to add new added header/source into VS:

1. need to generate in CMake again.
2. fake to edit the `CMakeLists.txt` a little bit, e.g. simply add a space. And then build your solution in VS, it will automatically add new header/source files.

Comment: but this will not include, for instance `header-folder/anotherdir/someheader.h`. How to fix that ?

Comment: @Shiro You can either add something like `header-folder/anotherdir/*.h` to the above or make use of [CMake subdirectories](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7787823/2589776).

Comment: `GLOB_RECURSE` instead of `GLOB` searches through sub-dirs as well ! That was what I needed.

Answer (score 12):

you need to add every `.h` and `.cpp` file to CMakeList.txt like this:

```
# Local header files here ONLY
SET(TARGET_H
    Header.h
    Plugin.h
    messagelog.h
    win32application.h
    timer.h    
   )

# Local source files here
SET(TARGET_SRC
    Plugin.cpp
    messagelog.cpp
    win32application.cpp
    timer.cpp
    )
```

then configure and build the solution again and reload it in VS.

Comment: Yes but then each time I want to add a nea header or .cpp file I have to rebuid the whole program using cmake.Can I do anything to achieve this through Visual Studio?

Comment: I don't have a windows environment handy but at least on linux, cmake gets called automatically when you try to build your sources. Except for the first cmake configure time, it's transparent for subsequent edits to any CMakeLists.txt file.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's a late Response and I just saw it. I am using **CLion IDE** from JetBrains, which a*dds these header and .cpp files automatically* when you create them. Although it may not be your need, it may be useful for other peoples who see it.