# How to make CPP files visible to linker in ESP8266 Eclipse project

Tags: c++, eclipse, esp8266

There is a "hello world" project in Eclipse IDE that is supposed to compile against ESP8266 RTOS SDK.

File structure is as follows

[image: project structure]

I added one C++ class to it and put it into its own folder. Here is the class header

```
#ifndef MAIN_BLINKER_BLINKER_H_
#define MAIN_BLINKER_BLINKER_H_

class Blinker {
public:
  Blinker( int period );
  int Period() const;
private:
  int period_;
};

#endif /* MAIN_BLINKER_BLINKER_H_ */
```

and the definitions

```
#include "Blinker.h"

Blinker::Blinker( int period ) :
  period_( period )
{}

int Blinker::Period() const {
  return this->period_;
}
```

Main.cpp file is like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "blinker/Blinker.h"

extern "C" {

void app_main()
{
  auto blnk = Blinker( 3000 );
  int i = 0;
  while ( 1 ) {
    printf( "[%d] Hello beautiful world!\n", i );
    i++;
    vTaskDelay( blnk.Period() / portTICK_PERIOD_MS );
  }
}

}
```

It compiles but fails at final stage because the linker (or what is supposed to be a linker in xtensa toolchain) does not see definitions of Blinker methods. This is what I get in the build log
[image: build errors]

If I put class files next to `main.cpp` file, the build succeeds. However with time there will be hundreds of files, and without any grouping it will quickly turn into an unmanageable mess.

Alternatively I could put this class into top-level `components` folder and equip it with empty `component.mk` file. This would also make the build system happy, however it would force me to use ugly header includes like `../components/blinker/Blinker.h`, which I would like to avoid.

So the question is how to make build system aware of .c and .cpp files residing in subfolders of `main` folder?

Comment: This appears to be using `make`, not Eclipse's own build system.

Comment: Yes, I already realized it myself. But how to correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set COMPONENT_SRCDIRS in "main" component.mk file

see:
https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp8266-rtos-sdk/en/latest/api-guides/build-system.html#example-component-makefiles

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `blinker/Blinker.cpp` to your `CMakeLists.txt`.
Take a look at
[How to add new source file in CMakeLists.txt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53592252/how-to-add-new-source-file-in-cmakelists-txt)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I believe CMake is not used by ESP8266 RTOS SDK. Regardless of what I have in CMakeLists.txt, e.g. blank file or intended syntax errors, the process of compilation follows the same scenario and ends with the same errors.