# Undefined symbol for custom .h and cpp using CMake

Tags: opengl, cmake, undefined-symbol

It's been over a decade since I used C++ and this whole CMake thing is completely new to me. My question is specifically how do I configure a CMake project so that it won't get this undefined symbol error.

The error message is below:

```
====================[ Build | glfw_template | Debug ]===========================
"/Users/brianyeh/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch-0/193.6911.21/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake" --build /Users/brianyeh/CLionProjects/glfw_template/cmake-build-debug --target glfw_template -- -j 4
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable bin/glfw_template
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_LoadShaders", referenced from:
      init() in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [bin/glfw_template] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/glfw_template.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/glfw_template.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [glfw_template] Error 2
```

Please reference this link to see the project: https://github.com/crimsonalucard/glfw_template

The desired behavior is that the project compiles under CMake.

Comment: It looks like you haven't actually created a function called LoadShaders, the cpp for LoadShaders is empty. Did you forget to implement it?

Comment: @NathanWride my bad, this is example code from the opengl redbook. I copied stuff over and reproduced the original error to make an example for Stack Overflow. I've corrected the error but the problem is still there.

Comment: It is requirement of the Stack Overflow to have code, reproducing the problem, to be **in the question post** itself, not *linked*. With over 2k reputation you should be aware of that... Please, fix the question post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build your executable with all of the .cpp files used in your project.

Examples from these links:

http://derekmolloy.ie/hello-world-introductions-to-cmake/

[Adding header and .cpp files in a project built with cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986353/adding-header-and-cpp-files-in-a-project-built-with-cmake)

Suggest doing something like this in your cmakelists:

```
file(GLOB SOURCES
    lib/*.cpp
    include/*.h
    main.cpp
)

add_executable(glfw_template ${SOURCES})
```

EDIT: As per comments GLOB is not recommended, the preferred method is to manually add all sources to a cultivated list:

```
set(SOURCES lib/LoadShaders.cpp lib/vgl.cpp)
set(HEADERS include/LoadShaders.h include/vgl.h)

add_executable(glfw_template ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})
```

Comment: The use of `GLOB` in CMake files is *not* a recommended practice. It is best to list all of the source files individually to avoid dependency issues in the future.

Comment: @squareskittles his solution worked though. I'm checking it for now, but if you have a better solution I'd be eager to hear it. Definitely don't want to not follow best practices but I also respect the fact that his solution worked.

Comment: I have edited the answer to provide an alternative to GLOB. We actually use the manual list at work so I'm sure that is better practice, I just thought GLOB is nice for a small project like this. Let me know if the edit works for you @BrianYeh

Comment: @BrianYeh Yes, `GLOB` works in many cases, particularly for small projects. But it doesn't keep track of source file changes for you, so sources added later on may not be recognized without a manual re-run of CMake. This is why it is typically not *recommended*, which is even evident in the CMake documentation (see the **Note** [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#filesystem)).

Comment: @NathanWride it worked. Thank you both of you.