# Generic CMakeLists.txt for specific project layout

Tags: cmake

All of my projects have the following structure tree:

```
project
|----utils
|    |----util_1
|    |    |----inc_directory(hpp files inside)
|    |    |----src_directory(cpp files inside)
|    ..........
|    ..........
|    |----util_n
|    |    |----inc_directory(hpp files inside)
|    |    |----src_directory(cpp files inside)
|
|----main.cpp
|----CMakeLists.txt
```

I want to write a generic `CMakeLists.txt` file that will allow me to compile any project which has the same structure.

Comment: You could use a mechanism similar to here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787823/cmake-how-to-get-the-name-of-all-subdirectories-of-a-directory and browse the directories and get the cpp files dynamically

Comment: That's not the way CMake works. Just add the utils and your are done, why adding complexity?