# Symbolic links from each target dir to common resources dir

Tags: cmake

I need to create symbolic links to directory `common_resources` which contains textures, fonts, 3D models, shaders, and is located in my `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`. I have to put such a link into all of my compiled binary target's working directories (~50 directories).

I can probably do it one-by-one by adding this `ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET` to each subfolder

```
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET( common_resources ALL  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E create_symlink ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/common_resources ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/common_resources )
```

but I do not want to do it because:

1. I don't want to to edit all those `CMakeList.txt` files and
2. I don't want to create so many custom targets for no reason. I use Code::Blocks IDE and I already have very long list of targets to select from, which makes it difficult to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is two-fold:

1. Write a function wrapping the custom command.
2. You have to automatically iterate over all sub-directories, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/7788165/2799037 how to do that. Call your function for every sub-directory.

Your second concern is probably a misconception. `custom_command` does not add a new target, that is only `custom_target`.

Comment: thanks, I' did not know how to use `custom_command`. Btw. do you have idea if it is possible to get rid of  all `target/fast` which cmake generate by default dogether with `target` ?