# How to get all directory name on a path in cmake?

Tags: cmake, directx-12

I want to write a cmake script to find directx 12 sdk's directory. This directory is in `$ENV{ProgramFiles}/Windows Kits/10/Include/`. However, on this path, it has many different version of the SDK which is stored on different directory. Such as 10.0.10150, 10.0.10240, 10.0.10586 and so on.

I don't know how many version of the SDK. So I want to get all directory on this path. But how should I do?
The directory like this:

- $ENV{ProgramFiles}/Windows Kits/10/Include/

  - 10.0.10150
  - 10.0.10240
  - 10.0.10586

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake : How to get the name of all subdirectories of a directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787823/cmake-how-to-get-the-name-of-all-subdirectories-of-a-directory)

Comment: Which version of CMake and which version of Visual Studio are you using? Because for Visual Studio 2015 and above the SDK version is in [`CMAKE_VS_WINDOWS_TARGET_PLATFORM_VERSION`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/variable/CMAKE_VS_WINDOWS_TARGET_PLATFORM_VERSION.html) global variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer*

According to ["Where is the DirectX SDK (2015 Edition)?"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2015/08/05/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2015-edition/) it's now part of the Windows 10 SDK (the paths you have added indicate you have already installed it).

If we are talking only about headers in the SDK, nothing is required from your side. Just include them and Visual Studio will find the right SDK headers (matching your project's settings).

To answer your question, I see the following possibilities (tested with my VS2015 Community Edition):

1. Using the CMake variable [`CMAKE_VS_WINDOWS_TARGET_PLATFORM_VERSION`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/variable/CMAKE_VS_WINDOWS_TARGET_PLATFORM_VERSION.html):

   ```
   file(TO_CMAKE_PATH "$ENV{ProgramFiles}" _progFilePath)
   message("${_progFilePath}/Windows Kits/10/Include/${CMAKE_VS_WINDOWS_TARGET_PLATFORM_VERSION}")
   ```

   Outputs on my machine

   > ```
   > C:/Program Files/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.14393.0
   > ```
2. Let CMake do the work of finding DirectX headers with [`find_file()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_file.html):

   ```
   find_file(_directXHeader "d3d9.h")
   get_filename_component(_directXPath "${_directXHeader}" DIRECTORY)
   message("${_directXPath}")
   ```

   Outputs on my machine

   > ```
   > C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.14393.0/shared
   > ```
3. Directly use Visual Studio macros like

   ```
   add_compile_options("/I%(WindowsSDK_IncludePath)")
   ```