# CMake: Getting a list of directories (non-recursive)

Tags: cmake

In CMake, how can I get a non-recursive list of directories that exist in a certain directory?
I can see that using GLOB isn't recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why wouldn't GLOB be recommended? That's what the GLOB is for. I love GLOB, especially in cases like this where it's extremely helpful to grab multiple items.

[The macro from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787823/cmake-how-to-get-the-name-of-all-subdirectories-of-a-directory) may be what you're looking for.

```
MACRO(SUBDIRLIST result curdir)
  FILE(GLOB children RELATIVE ${curdir} ${curdir}/*)
  SET(dirlist "")
  FOREACH(child ${children})
    IF(IS_DIRECTORY ${curdir}/${child})
      LIST(APPEND dirlist ${child})
    ENDIF()
  ENDFOREACH()
  SET(${result} ${dirlist})
ENDMACRO()
```

You basically grab the items from the current source directory, check to see if it's a directory, and if so, append it to a list.

Credit to refaim in the link for that macro.